# Add permission in the app in RingCentral production

Tags: permissions, ringcentral

We are working in RingCentral application and APIs with SMS and fax permissions.

The application recently moved to production from Sandbox environment.
We have now a requirement to add 2 additional permission **ReadAccount**, **ReadContact** in the app which was not added during sandbox  testing.
How can we do that? I don't see any option to modify the app. Is there any way we can modify the existing app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per I know once your app is in production, you cannot change anything.

You need to ask **devsupport@ringcentral.com** for any help. Once they added the permission with your request (not sure if they do.. most probably they don't) you need to test again for that permission you acquired.

The official recommendation is to create a new app, add proper permissions and graduate it. So in that case you need to go through again.

As per the reference here
"***You can clone the app, give it a new name or add a version to the new app name. Add the missing permissions and run test in the sandbox the same way as you did for the first app. Graduate your app and finally replace the client Id and secrete to use the new app. You can suspend the old app after that.***"

Similar question here: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1059/how-to-add-permissions-of-read-call-log-in-product.html